# Run time Error 3201 when reading Database and missing the last entry

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am currently struggling with this piece of Code:

```
While receiver = data.Fields("Contact")
    If first Then
        first = False
        strSig = Replace(strSig, ID, data.Fields("ID") & ID)
    Else
        strSig = Replace(strSig, ID, ", " & data.Fields("ID") & ID)
    End If

    data.MoveNext
Wend
```

It is not reading the last database entry.

My complete code is doing the following:

1. Read Database
2. Read an HTML File
3. Search for multiple IDs for a person and aggregate those
4. Replace the IDs with a placeholder in the IDs
5. Send the Email

The process does work except for for the last entry. For that entry I receive a

> 3021 Run Time Error - No Current Record.

Comment: The error is caused by VBA getting to the end of the recordset.  You'll need to share more specific information and examples of your data.  Check out the [tour] (and earn a badge for doing so!), and also see [ask] as well as how to create a [mcve].

Comment: So this is how the table looks like:

Comment: You should check for data.eof()

Comment: @SundeepKang I updated my answer with a second example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to loop through a recordset:

```
Option Explicit

Sub recordsetDemo()

    'can use the name of a table or of a query, or a specific SQL query:
    Const rs_Source = "select * from tblYourTable"

    Dim rs As Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(rs_Source) 'open the recordset
    With rs  'refer to the RS with "." dots instead of the full name "rs."
        If Not .EOF Then .MoveFirst 'move to the first record
        Do While Not .EOF 'keep doing this until the end of the recordset


            Debug.Print !myField1, !myField2  'do "something" here with the data.


            .MoveNext 'move to the next record
        Loop 'loop will end if there's no "next record"
        .Close 'close the recordset
    End With
    Set rs = Nothing 'clear the variable

End Sub
```

---

A rough adaptation using your example:

```
Sub recordsetDemo()

    Dim data As Recordset
    Set data = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("YourTableOrQueryName") 'open recordset

  '***however you setup your "Data" recordset could replace the above code***

    With data
        If .EOF Then 'check if there's data
            MsgBox "No Data Found!"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        .MoveFirst 'move to the first record
        Do While Not .EOF 'keep doing this until the end of the recordset

            If first Then
                first = False
                strSig = Replace(strSig, id, !id & id)
            Else
                strSig = Replace(strSig, id, ", " & !id & id)
            End If

            .MoveNext 'move to the next record

        Loop 'loop will end if there's no "next record"
        .Close 'close the recordset
    End With
    Set rs = Nothing 'clear the variable
End Sub
```

That's all I can do given the information you provided.

Comment: IIRC `.MoveFirst` would throw if `rs` returns no records.. no?

Comment: It would; I added an `IF` to prevent that. (Technically there is lots of other things that could go wrong too... it's just a basic example.)  :-)